# Why is $f(n) = n + 6 \mod{1729}$ not injective?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, discrete-mathematics

The exercise was to determine if the function $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{1729}, f(n) = n + 6 \mod{1729}$ is injective or not.

My thinking was that 
$f(-7) = 1728\\ 
f(-6) = 0\\ 
f(-5) = 1\\
\vdots\\
f(0) = 6\\ 
f(1) = 7\\ 
\vdots\\
f(1722)=1728\\ 
f(1723) = 0$

and so on, we will get all numbers in $\mathbb{Z}_{1729}$.

However, this turned out to be wrong, but the solution doesn't say why, though. Why is this function not injective?

Comment: Are you mixing surjective and injective?

Comment: We have $f(-6)=f(1723)$ and $-6\ne 1723$. Therefore, $f$ is not injective.

Comment: You are definitely confusing surjective with injection.  $f(x + 1729) = f(x)$ while $x+1729 \ne x$ is enough to prove $f$ is *NOT* injective.  Injective means that for any $k \in \mathbb Z_{1729}$ then there is at most one (although there might not be any) $a\in \mathbb Z$ so that $f(a) = k$.  Because $f(k-6 + 1729n) = k$ for all $n$ this is obviously FALSE.

Comment: On the other hand *surjective* means that for any $k \in \mathbb Z_{1729}$ there is at *least* one (although there might be more) $a \in \mathbb Z$ so that $f(a) = k$.  Because $f(k-6  + 1729n) =k$ we know that for any $k$ there are infinite solutions.  So every $k$ has at least one solution so $f$ is surjective.  But some $k$ (in fact all of them) has more than one solution so $f$ is *not* surjective.

Comment: Yes, I totally got the two mixed up! Now that you mention it, it makes complete sense that this is not injetice (one-to-one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be thinking surjective, meaning that the image of $\mathbb{Z}$ under $f$ is all of $\mathbb{Z}_{1729}$. Injective means there would not be two different integers, say $n,m$ such that $f(n)=f(m)$. Equivalently, if $f(n)=f(m)$ then we must have $n=m$.

This cannot be the case for $f$ since it repeats at least every 1729 integers. For example, 
$$
f(0)=0+6 \equiv 0 \mod 1729
$$
$$
f(0+1729)=f(1729)=1729 \equiv 0 \mod 1729
$$
In fact, this will work for any integer $n$: $f(n+1729)=f(n)$. So $f$ cannot be injective.

Answer (score 4):

There is no injective function from an infinite set to a finite one.

Comment: This is such a nice answer. It made me smile.:)

Answer (score 1):

You are definitely confusing surjective with injection.

*SUR*jective means "we will get all the numbers in $\mathbb Z_{1729}$".

*IN*jective means "we will never get any number in $\mathbb Z_{1729}$ more than once".

$f(-6) = 0$ and $f(1723) = 0$ is enough to prove we get some numbers at least twice.

So $f$ is *NOT* injective.

.......

Injective means if $f: X\to Y$ then for any $k \in Y$ there is *at most one* $a \in X$ so that $f(a) = k$.

Surjcetive means if $f: X \to Y$ then for every $k \in Y$ there is *at least one* $a \in X$ so that $f(a) = k$.

So if $f(a) = k$ has solutions for *every* $k$ it is surjective.  If for *any* $k$, $f(a) = k$ does not have a solution it is not surjective.

And if $f(a) = k$ has a *unique* or *no* solution for every $k$ it is injective.  If for any$ $k$, $f(a) = $k\in \mathbb Z_{1729}$ *more* than one solution it is not injective.

For any $k \in \mathbb Z_{1729}$ then $f(k - 6 + n\cdot 1729)=k$.

So for any $k$ there is more than one solution.  So it is *not* injective.

And for *every* $k$ there is at least one solution (infinitely many in fact).  So it *is* surjective.